# Oracle Partitioned Table - How to Count

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, partitioning

I have a partitioned table (MYTABLE) on Oracle (11g). 
This is a quite large table, partitioned by INSERT_DATE column (without time).

The problem is that, **Count(*) gives incorrect result**.

The query below returns: 5,726,829,673

```
SELECT count(*) FROM MYTABLE WHERE INSERT_DATE >= TO_DATE('01/01/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

The query below returns: 13,076,228,720

```
SELECT SUM(1) FROM MYTABLE WHERE INSERT_DATE >= TO_DATE('01/01/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

How can it be possible? What is the reason for this difference?

Comment: I might have an idea. What's your exact 11g version?  `SELECT * FROM V$VERSION`

Comment: It is Exadata machine. Details are: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE 11.2.0.4.0 Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

Comment: ok same here. I thought that you had encountered the [Bug 9857247  Wrong results for count(*) with group by placement](https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=bug&id=9857247) affecting versions _11.2.0.1_ and _11.2.0.2_ but it's not the case as it was fixed in _11.2.0.3_ . It's weird, wondering if someone as an explanation...

Comment: Any chance those numbers are backward? (The count the higher number?)

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Note` section of the execution plans for the two queries - is there a plan management feature causing the queries to use radically different plans?  Run `explain plan for SELECT ...` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);` to find out if Oracle is running the queries differently.

For example, a DBA might have created a SQL profile on `count(*)` version, forcing the optimizer to use an index, and that index is corrupt and needs to be rebuilt.

Or some evil developer used `DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE` to literally change the query text, but only for one of the statements.  Check for any entries in `DBA_REWRITE_EQUIVALENCES`.